# JSF facelet page doesn't javascript string with '&' character

Tags: javascript, jsf, facelets

in a JSF facelet page (.xhtml) I have this javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function navigateToDetail() {
            var id = document.getElementById("idElemento").value;
            alert(id);
            var isPratica = document.getElementById("isPratica").value;
            alert(isPratica);
            var box = "#{boxCtrl.idBox}";
            alert(box);             
            if (isPratica==true)
                window.location = "DettaglioRichiesta.xhtml?id=" + id + "&box=" + box;
            else
                window.location = "../Richieste/DettaglioRichiesta.xhtml?id=" + id + "&box=" + box;

        }
    </script>
```

It doesn't work because the jfs engine think that "&box" is relative to a bindign, and it says:

```
Error Parsing /Box/ListaRichieste.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 20] The reference to entity "box" must end with the ';' delimiter
```

I can I avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Facelets is a XML based view technology. The `&` is a [XML special character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML). It's interpreted as start of a XML entity like `&nbsp;`, `&#160;`, etc. It is therefore looking for the end character `;`, but it found none, so it is throwing this error.

To represent the `&` literally inside a XML document, you need to use `&amp;` instead of `&`.

```js
window.location = "DettaglioRichiesta.xhtml?id=" + id + "&amp;box=" + box;
```

You can also just put that JS code in its own `.js` file which you include by `<script src>` so that you don't need to fiddle with XML special characters in the JS code.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="your.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks I knew about the external js file, but I was curious to solve it "in page". Thanks for the solution